# PhpStorm/WebStorm REST client editor: Using variables in JSON

Tags: phpstorm, httpclient, webstorm

I cannot use variables from `http-client.env.json` within the body as the following

```
POST {{host}}/{{locale}}/foo
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "email": {{email}},
  "password": {{password}}
}
```

so the string interpolation `{{email}}` is not being recognized for some reason as if it's not supported yet, and whenever I'm changing my code to hardly coded values as the following snippet things will be just fine!

```
POST {{host}}/{{locale}}/foo
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "email": "info@example.com",
  "password": "saynomore"
}
```

And obviously extracting the body into its own external JSON file is not an option.

Comment: What PhpStorm version are you using? It's supported [since 2018.2.7](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-40409) and also it [works just fine](http://prntscr.com/r1f69k) for me.

Comment: I'm using 2019.3, this is very odd, I just tried it and it didn't work for me :(

Comment: I have no idea. Please record a similar screencast: https://recordit.co/DdmO7UbOyr

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options for how to use variables.

**1)** Preferable one. Create `json.env` file and put all your vars in the format

```
{
  "<env name>": {
    "<variable name>": "<value>"
  }
}
```

You can autogenerate it in the upper menu. Where you have a drop-down with a list of environments.

`Environment` here is not more, than a selected list of variables. More information with pictures you can find here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/exploring-http-syntax.html#c3cb9d37

**2)** Set variables in "run configuration". It is the same as any other "run configuration" in JetBrains products. You can find it at the top near the green arrow.

**3)** Write values in pre-script. This will look something like

```
< {%
    request.variables.set("host", "HTTP://some.web.adress")
%}
POST {{host}}/{{locale}}/foo
...
```

You can autogenerate it as well with the context menu

Check full documentation if you have more questions:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/exploring-http-syntax.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).